# INSERT ALL fails with trigger setting timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let's say we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table 
(
    text   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    text2  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    ts     TIMESTAMP
);
```

And we want to insert some data using `INSERT ALL`:

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO test_table ( text, text2 ) VALUES ( 'test', 'test2' ) 
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

The result is

```
1 row inserted.
```

But, when we want to add trigger, to fill `ts` column with `SYSTIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON  test_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('text=' || :new.text);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('text2=' || :new.text2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ts=' || :new.ts);
    :new.ts := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;
/
```

Running the same script

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;
INSERT ALL 
    INTO test_table ( text, text2 ) VALUES ( 'test', 'test2' ) 
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

The result is:

```
text=test
text2=
ts=
INSERT ALL 
INTO test_table ( text, text2 ) VALUES ( 'test', 'test2' ) 
SELECT * FROM dual
Error report -
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TEST"."TEST_TABLE"."TEXT2")
```

Using `INSERT` works fine

```
SET SERVEROUT ON;
INSERT INTO test_table ( text, text2 ) VALUES ( 'test', 'test2' )
```

The result is

```
text=test
text2=test2
ts=
1 row inserted.
```

Also this works:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO test_table ( text, text2, ts) VALUES ( 'test', 'test2', null ) 
SELECT * FROM dual
```

When I change `ts` column type to `DATE` works fine with this kind of trigger.
I'm using `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`, I've also checked on `Oracle 12c` but there is no error, so maybe it's some kind of bug in 11g release?

Comment: Very odd. I was able to reproduce it also.  Regular insert works.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing seems wrong with your code, it may be a bug with version you are using.
That said, what you are trying to achieve is more usually done by following create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    text   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    text2   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    ts    TIMESTAMP not null default systimestamp
);
```

You will not need trigger for this at all.